# Use multiple regex to check blacklisted patterns are there in the string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with value. I want to check whether there are back listed pattern there in that string.

ex: `String myString="a/b[c=\"1\"=\"1\"]/c\^]`

I want to check following patterns are there

1. "1"="1"
2. ^

I am using following code which always gives false

```
         String text    = "\"1\"=\"1\" ^ for occurrences of the http:// pattern.";

        String patternString = "\"1\"=\"1\"|^";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        boolean matches = matcher.matches();

        System.out.println("matches = " + matches)
```

How can I check it with one line of regex.

Comment: `"1"="1"` and `^` must be the two in the String or just one of them?

Comment: should be two in the string

Comment: How do you accept @anubhava answer when `"1"="1"` and `^` should both be in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code:

```
String patternString = "\"1\"=\"1\"|^";
```

Here `^` must be escaped since `^` is a special meta character so make it:

```
String patternString = "\"1\"=\"1\"|\\^";
```

Then this call:

```
boolean matches = matcher.matches();
```

should be changed to:

```
boolean matches = matcher.find();
```

as `matches` attempts to match full input string.

Comment: But the OP wants a String to contains `"1"="1"` **AND** `^` not **OR**.

Comment: In that case 2 calls to `str.contains` and no regex

Answer (score 1):

To check if **BOTH** `"1"="1"` and `^` are in the input String

*Using regex:*

```
String text    = "\"1\"=\"1\"  ^ for occurrences of the http:// pattern.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"1\"=\"1\".*\\^|\\^.*\"1\"=\"1\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if(m.find())
    System.out.println("Correct String");
```

*Using `contains` method:*

```
String text    = "\"1\"=\"1\"  ^ for occurrences of the http:// pattern.";
if (text.contains("\"1\"=\"1\"") && text.contains("^"))
        System.out.println("Correct String");
```